# How to check if a file is text file (English, Chinese and Japanese)

Tags: java

Using Java, how to check whether a file is a text file that could be opened with a text editor? (Assume text editor supports any necessary encoding.) Text file language could be English, Chinese or Japanese.

Comment: Do you not know the encoding to start with? What exactly counts as "a text file that could be opened with a text editor"?

Comment: Default encoding is UTF-8. For the test case, I created a text file using Notepad and input some Chinese/Japanese characters. Then how to use java to check whether the file is a text file. In production file extension could be anything. So I have to check the content. Thanks

Comment: You could try seeing if it contains common words from each language, but am pretty sure there is no definite way to determine if it is to be interpreted as plain text

Comment: The file extension is irrelevant... It's not too hard to check whether it's valid UTF-8, but if it's an unknown encoding, that's a different matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
File f = new File("file_location here");
System.out.println(new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(f));
```

It prints out `text/plain` for text files.

Comment: Just an update. MimeTypesFileTypeMap#getContentType() actually checks the file extension to determine the return type. So it returns "application/octet-stream" for a text file without any file extension. But it does help me in many test cases.